# Laravel 5.4: No cargan las rutas en virtualhost (Error 404)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, apache, configuración, virtualhost

He configurado casi-exitosamente un virtualhost usando Apache para trabajar con Laravel 5.4 (inicialmente estuve trabajando con Homestead pero "x" razones ahora estoy trabajando localmente).

El problema es que a pesar que si logra cargar la página inicial, no puedo acceder a consultar las rutas "api" de Laravel, así, si yo tengo la ruta:

http://ventas.dev

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero obtener los resultados de la siguiente ruta:

http://ventas.dev/api/perfil

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**No funciona.** Más bien obtengo el error 404. No se si debo hacer más configuraciones, pero esto es lo que tengo en la configuración de mi virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin user@dominio.com
    ServerName ventas.dev
    ServerAlias www.ventas.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Ventas/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/Ventas/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

¿Alguna idea de lo que podría estar haciendo mal?

Comment: HOla amigo tienes que primero apuntar a la ruta www.tudominio.com/public/api/perfil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno, ya arreglé mi problema. Era necesario dar permisos 777 al directorio storage:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
```

y habilitar el mod_rewrite:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Por ultimo, es necesario reiniciar el servidor (en mi caso Apache):

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

That's it